# I tried activating zhs and antigen theme I end up getting errors while opening my vagrant. Whenever I vagrant ssh I will find myself @ ubuntu-focal~

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04, vagrant-windows

PS C:\Users\Mukaddas> vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-48-generic x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
- Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
- Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantate

System information as of Wed Oct  5 15:53:32 UTC 2022

System load:  0.15380859375      Processes:               106
Usage of /:   13.2% of 38.70GB   Users logged in:         1
Memory usage: 22%                IPv4 address for enp0s3: 10.0.2.15
Swap usage:   0%

- Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
  footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

  https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

21 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this